# JSON parse throws exception :

Tags: java, json

I have a list which contains Objects of OClass . I want to create the JSON of this Objects . Here's my code:

```
public void getClasss() {

    // returns all the top classes present in the ontology.

    classlist = new ArrayList<OClass>();     
    Set<OClass> topclasses = ontology.getOClasses(true);
    for (OClass oClasses : topclasses) {                
        classlist.add(oClasses);                
    }   

    OntoCreationClass ocreat = new OntoCreationClass();

    ocreat.OntoCreation(classlist);   
}

public class OntoCreationClass {    
    public static String data;
    public void OntoCreation(List<OClass> list) {

        System.out.println(list.get(0));

        OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            mapper.writeValue(out, list);
        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }
}
```

Exception is :

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer
>            found for class com.ontotext.trree.owlim_ext.r and no properties
>            discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable
>            SerializationConfig.SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
>            (through reference chain:
>            java.util.ArrayList[0]->gate.creole.ontology.impl.OClassImpl["ontology"]-gate.creole.ontology.impl.sesame.OWLIMOntology["service"]-gate.creole.ontology.impl.sesame.OntologyServiceImplSesame["sesameManager"]-gate.creole.ontology.impl.sesame.SesameManager["repositoryConnection"]-org.openrdf.repository.sail.SailRepositoryConnection["repository"]-org
>
> ```
> .openrdf.repository.sail.SailRepository["sail"]-com.ontotext.trree.owlim_ext.SailImpl["pool"])
> ```
>
> >

How can i solve this error ? can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

If the Access Modifiers of fields in your class are `private`, then you must put Setter and Getter to make this class Serializable.

Look this sample code to store list of objects of `Person` class:

1- `Person` class:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

2- Add `Person` object to the `List`:

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
persons.add(new Person("Mike", 26));
persons.add(new Person("David", 20));
persons.add(new Person("Sara", 21));
persons.add(new Person("Amanda", 15));
```

3- Then you can use `writeValue` right now:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        objectMapper.writeValue(new FileOutputStream(jsonPath), persons);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

4- Finally you can see you `JSON` file:

```
[{"name":"Mike","age":26},{"name":"David","age":20},{"name":"Sara","age":21},{"name":"Amanda","age":15}]
```